# 4-bit input, 5-bit output, logical right shift by 2, which is the correct set of 5 output bits?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Suppose I have the following inputs:

1110
1111

If I perform a logical right shift by 2 on each, are the 5-bit outputs these:

00111
00111

or these:

01110
01111

If it's neither, then I'd appreciate an explain why and what I've done wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do a shift: either the "new"  digit (the leftmost, msb) is set to zero, or it is set to the digit that was there before. The former is usually called *logical shift* while the latter preserves the sign of the number (in case you use the complement representation) and is called *arithmetic shift*. But sometimes both are just called shift, and one needs to clarify the desired behavior.

Since you as about buffers of length 5 bits, the msb is anyway 0 so logical shift-arithmetic shift, and I'd say the 2-bit right shift is:

```
01110  -> 00111 -> 00011
01111  -> 00111 -> 00011
```